# Error [42000] MySQL in C# application

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql, odbc

I have a C# window application that works well including report generation but suddenly when I try to generate a report an error appeared.

> ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysql-5.0.16-nt]You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right  syntax to use...

The line which has the error is a `Select` statement, so I try it on MySQL query browser and it was executed successfully no error encountered.

Comment: Show us your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: `Select " + FieldName + " from tblYearToDate where EmployeeID = " +EmployeeID + " and YTDYear = '" + Year + "'`

Comment: @shio can you show us the select right before its executed ? to see how its build-ed

Comment: @Stephan what do you mean?

Comment: @shio i mean to see the final query when the variables are concatenated

Comment: `Select GrossBasic from tblYearToDate where EmployeeID = 553 and YTDYear = '2012'` -like that?

Answer (score 0):

You're vulnerable to `SQL Injection`.  Use paramerterised queries.

```
Select " + FieldName + " from tblYearToDate where EmployeeID = " +EmployeeID + " and YTDYear = '" + Year + "'
```

If theres no validation against `Year` I could enter `;DROP TABLE tblYearToDate`

I believe the reason for the original error is because `EmployeeId` needs to be wrapped in `'`s.

To use parameters simply do:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT FieldNAme FROM tblYearToDate WHERE EmployeeId = @EmployeeId AND YTDYear = @Year");

cmd.Paramaters.Add("@EmployeeId").Value = EmployeeID
cmd.Paramaters.Add("@Year").Value = Year

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: so, i need also to put `'` on the `EmployeeID`?

Comment: @shio - yes. So the value looks like '1' - also use the parameters to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: ok thanks I'll try your solution. Another thing is my app generated the report successfully on different laptop but on my laptop there was an error but days ago it perfectly works in my laptop. What's wrong with my app?

Comment: @shio - it would be difficult for me to attempt to answer without seeing the full code or even both of the laptops.

Comment: oh i see. anyways, thanks and i'll try first your solution but as of now i am using a different laptop so the whole app is working but the app will be deployed to my laptop so i really need to solve that issue.